# CI pipeline for AWS ECS from gitlab repository

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to create a pipeline for ECS deployment.

So my .gitlab-ci.yml file is like that:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - review
  - deploy
  - production
  - cleanup

variables:
  AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET: ECS
  CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER: shopservice
  CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE: sample-app-service
  CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: first-run-task-definition:1
  AWS_REGION: us-west-2

include:
  - template: Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/Deploy/ECS.gitlab-ci.yml
```

But on the stage production_ecs my pipeline was failed. And I gettin an error as :

```
Using docker image sha256:9920fa2b45873efd675cf992d7130e8a691133fd51ec88b2765d977f82695263 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-ecs:latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-ecs@sha256:c833e508b00451a09639e96fb7551f62abb4f75ba1d31f88b4dc8299c608e0dd ...
22$ ecs update-task-definition
23Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

25
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
27ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Why I'm getting this error? How can I configure was on ECS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your credentials (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) as environment variables and also set the region as environment variable  `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. You can set them by going to your project (or group) and navigate to `Settings > CI/CD`.

You can find the documentation for ecs deployments here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#deploy-your-application-to-the-aws-elastic-container-service-ecs

and for configuring the aws cli (which is used in the template and GitLab AWS Docker images) here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#run-aws-commands-from-gitlab-cicd